# why am i getting horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

so this is my html code -

```css
    /**
 font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-family: 'Alex Brush', cursive;
 font-family: 'Six Caps', sans-serif;
**/

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 100%;
}

#main {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('../assets/images/bgpattern.png');
}

#vidbox {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: -1;
}

#bgvid{
 width: 100%;
}

#vidfallback{
 width: 100%;
}

#navbar {
 width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#navbar li {
 float: right;
}

#navbar li a {
 display: block;
 color: rgb(35,85,125);
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 28px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 35px 40px;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
 color: #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
}

#navbar li a:active{
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
}

#logo {
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.left {
 float: left!important;
 background-color: rgb(35,85,125);
}

.white{
 color: #fff!important;
}

#tagline{
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: 'Alex Brush', cursive;
 margin: 130px;
 color: #fff;
}

.bigger{
 font-size: 80px;
}

.box{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Testing</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush|Josefin+Sans|Montserrat+Subrayada|Six+Caps" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="main">
      <div id="vidbox">
       <video autoplay  poster="" id="bgvid" loop>
        <source src="assets/video/filxe.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img src="assets/images/vidfallback.png" id="vidfallback">
       </video>
      </div>
      <ul id="navbar">
       <li class="left"><img src="assets/images/logomini.png" id="logo"></li>
       <li class="left"><a href="" class="white">HK Construction Company</a></li>
       <li><a href="#home" id="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h1 id="tagline"><span class="bigger">"</span> You Dream, We Build <span class="bigger">"</span></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box about">
      
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't understand that why am i getting the horizontal scroll bar in the browser. i tried everything like giving all of them 0 padding & 0 margin, nothing seems to work so can any of you look out the culprit.

Comment: maybe something is overflowing your content. Try overflow-x:none;

Comment: For your code snippet, there is no horizontal scroll bar. I'm in Chrome under Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the vw unit determines its size based on the width of the viewport. However, browsers calculate the viewport size as the browser window, which includes the space for the scrollbar.

if you set an element as 100vw, the element will extend outside the html and body elements and This caused the horizontal scroll.

**So :**

**Change :**

```
body {

    width:100vw;

}
```

**To :**

```
body {

    width:100%;

}
```

**Full code:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
}

#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../assets/images/bgpattern.png');
}

#vidbox {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bgvid{
    width: 100%;
}

#vidfallback{
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#navbar li {
    float: right;
}

#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(35,85,125);
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 40px;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
}

#navbar li a:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
    box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgb(35,85,125);
}

#logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.left {
    float: left!important;
    background-color: rgb(35,85,125);
}

.white{
    color: #fff!important;
}

#tagline{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Alex Brush', cursive;
    margin: 130px;
    color: #fff;
}

.bigger{
    font-size: 80px;
}

.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Testing</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush|Josefin+Sans|Montserrat+Subrayada|Six+Caps" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="main">
      <div id="vidbox">
       <video autoplay  poster="" id="bgvid" loop>
        <source src="assets/video/filxe.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img src="assets/images/vidfallback.png" id="vidfallback">
       </video>
      </div>
      <ul id="navbar">
       <li class="left"><img src="assets/images/logomini.png" id="logo"></li>
       <li class="left"><a href="" class="white">HK Construction Company</a></li>
       <li><a href="#home" id="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h1 id="tagline"><span class="bigger">"</span> You Dream, We Build <span class="bigger">"</span></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box about">
      
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```